# Spring Security principal cannot be found from SpEL

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I want to get data from `CrudRepository` for `RestResource` by a JPA Query:

```
public interface IContactRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Contact, Long> {

    @Query("select contact from Contact contact where contact.owner.login = ?#{principal.username}")
    @RestResource( path = "my")
    List<Contact> findByOwner();
}
```

But I get this:

> Property or field 'principal' cannot be found on object of type
>   'java.lang.Object[]' - maybe not public?

I can get principal directly:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

but I need it inside the interface to get direct access to `RestResource`.

Comment: See here. Loks like you need some config to enable this. https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions#spel-evaluationcontext-extension-model

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was facing the same problem and I fixed it by doing:

> provide a bean of type SecurityEvaluationContextExtension

as the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#data-configuration) said.

Below are Java and XML configurations from the [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#data-configuration):

**Java Configuration**

```
@Bean
public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension securityEvaluationContextExtension() {
    return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
}
```

**XML Configuration**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.data.repository.query.SecurityEvaluationContextExtension"/>
```

Hope this helps :)